# In a given file use line with short length as a key and longer length as a value and get the output in another file

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a text file which looks something like this

```
729590
fbe2d8c9-5b33-4758-8668-7e9f9f70085b
326e9ee4-da56-44de-ad40-e42f14dbf6c4
459590
d43bcb29-7c91-411c-ad5a-7450a927d2df
865431
f719b802-a7bd-4b83-aa02-08e3d3f351ff
8fcb6aed-9c87-4c0d-af94-9200830c4e27
c56378e8-fb14-4cd4-b816-020b328fb50a
345621
9fd92086-e681-4458-9631-cfa02d349fee
16cf1a8d-3fd8-49a3-b9fd-445a1413d280
07f31e67-07a4-4088-8cdd-9354d26cbd70
d6af1a35-563e-4e51-8533-0ec0a39d26fa
e7ae32e8-3658-400b-ab95-5107bedb6f34
```

Using this file I would want to get an output in another csv file in a format shown below

```
729590,fbe2d8c9-5b33-4758-8668-7e9f9f70085b,some_text
729590,326e9ee4-da56-44de-ad40-e42f14dbf6c4,some_text
459590,d43bcb29-7c91-411c-ad5a-7450a927d2df,some_text
865431,f719b802-a7bd-4b83-aa02-08e3d3f351ff,some_text
865431,8fcb6aed-9c87-4c0d-af94-9200830c4e27,some_text
865431,c56378e8-fb14-4cd4-b816-020b328fb50a,some_text
345621,9fd92086-e681-4458-9631-cfa02d349fee,some_text
345621,16cf1a8d-3fd8-49a3-b9fd-445a1413d280,some_text
345621,07f31e67-07a4-4088-8cdd-9354d26cbd70,some_text
345621,d6af1a35-563e-4e51-8533-0ec0a39d26fa,some_text
345621,e7ae32e8-3658-400b-ab95-5107bedb6f34,some_text
```

I have already written code to do it with the help of while loop but wanted to know that is their any other simple way to do it, may be using awk command.

Comment: Please read [ask] as well as how to create a [mcve]. You’ve shown none of your work and there is no specific question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your "grouping key" is a number with 6 digits (`729590`, `459590`, `865431`, `345621`), the following should work:

```bash
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=","} /^[0-9]{6}$/ {i=$0; next} {print i, $0, "some_text"}' input.txt
```

**Explanation**:

- `BEGIN{OFS=","}` will define `,` as a separator when we will call `print` function (e.g. `print "a", "b"` will display `a,b`)
- `/^[0-9]{6}/ {i=$0; next}` matches a 6-digit number, and stores it in variable `i`. Then it goes to the next line (`next`)
- `{print i, $0, "some_text"}`: for every other line, it prints the variable `i`, the current line (`$0`, in your case an `uuid`), and `some_text`. Each field will be separated by a `,` (defined by `OFS`)

Thanks to [@Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton) for his suggestion in the comments section :)

Comment: Not sure what you’re answering - the OP shared no code, yet wants a “simpler” solution - this is impossible to answer objectively (aside from there being nothing specific to answer)

Comment: @EdMorton: thank you very much, I've updated my answer. @DavidMakogon: OP told he has *already written code to do it with the help of while loop* so I assumed he used a `bash` script with `while`. He was just asking if it was **possible** to do the same with `awk`, which is definitively possible. Even if there is no question mark, his implicit question was clear enough for me :)